# MySQL Merging InnoDb and MyiSAM tables

Tags: merge, innodb, synchronization, myisam, full-text-search

I'm creating a small search engine for some data and need to use MyiSAM because of it's full-text search feature.  Unfortunately I also need to use transactions for commits and rollbacks to ensure entry of the data that will be searched.

I've created an InnoDb table for data storage (because it can do commit and rollback), and a MyiSAM table that is an exact copy of the InnoDb table for using full-text search. The problem now is keeping these tables in sync.

I'm looking for an efficient way to keep the MyiSAM table synced with the InnoDb table.  I can't use triggers because I don't want anything stored in the MyiSAM table until data is committed to the InnoDb table.

I'm okay with writing some code that will sync the tables on commit, but I'm not sure of a fast way to combine the two tables.  The tables may potentially be huge and I don't want the user waiting an hour to insert one record.  In the same context, I don't want the user to be unable to access the search engine at some time in the day for an hour as a cron job syncs the two tables and locks the MyiSAM table.

One thing to mention too, is my MySQL server is on Bluehost and therefore MySQL is locked on version 5.1, so I can't use the new InnoDb full-text search with version 5.6.  And of course I can't install any third party search server like sphinx on Bluehost.

If anyone has a good solution to my problem, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old question, but for people hitting this question on their search: InnoDB tables support FULLTEXT indexes starting in MySQL 5.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slight workaround

1. Setup MySQL Replication
2. On the Master

   - drop the FULLTEXT index on the MyISAM table
   - convert the MyISAM table to InnoDB
3. On the Slave

   - convert the InnoDB table back to MyISAM
   - recreate the FULLTEXT index on the MyISAM table

Going forward

- do all your INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs on the Master.
- do all your FULLTEXT searching on the Slave.

I have suggested this before: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/22425/877